Name for this network range formatting?
I'm working with an FTP server that only accepts IP ranges in this format:
192.168.128-255.0-255

What's the proper name for that format or presentation ?
It is none of:

CIDR: 192.168.128.0/17
Subnet mask: 192.168.128.0/255.255.128.0
Classful notation: not valid for this block, would be something like "128 class C networks"


The FTP server in question is "CompleteFTP" running on Windows, probably not relevant.

The name is "non-standard". SCNR

There is no name for such a notation. It doesn't adhere to any standard.
There's also some ambiguity involved that the product documentation does not address: it is not obvious which range 192.168.0-127.0-127 would refer to,

192.168.0.0 through 192.168.127.127 contiguously (including e.g. 192.168.1.128) or
separate sections 192.168.0.0 through 192.168.0.127 plus 192.168.1.0 through 192.168.1.127 and so on (excluding e.g. 192.168.1.128).

If the CIDR or subnet-based notation isn't flexible enough, the wildcard notation used with ACLs should be preferred, e.g. 192.168.0.0/0.0.127.127 for any address from 192.168.{0..127}.{0..127}.

I agree - its an inefficient and error-prone attempt to recreate something that was already better.   The only reason is perhaps its easier for the devs to interpret in code is my best guess.

@Criggie Only easier if you treat dotted-octet notation as a string - which you never ever should. An IPv4 address is an unsigned 32-bit integer, always.

yeah this is 10+ years old FTP/SCP server running under Windows - wouldn't have been my first choice, but it has some versatile hooks for authentication against the customer database.   Worst thing, its not the most legacy stuff we got running in prod :-\

There's no ambiguity, and it's easy to parse/process in code: addr[2] >= 0 && addr[2] <= 127. (and the same for addr[3])

@Ricky So you can rule out that neither the server developer nor any user understands  that notation like in the first variant in my answer? Imho, ambiguity in security-related functions is utter foolishness.

If you can't understand "this octet must be in this range", I don't know how to help you. Network engineers deal in bits. Everyone else deals in decimal; and 99% of the population doesn't know those "four numbers" are a way to represent 32bits. I would bet the devs had a (or "many") request to support this lunacy.

Yeah it doesn't fill me with confidence, hence why this service is being deprecated and replaced with an scp-based service
